# Is it possible to store a hydra somewhere?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I recently bought a Hydra. I thought it won't be possible since I don't own a hangar or something, lol.

Anyways, I can now call Pegasus and they drop it at the nearest spot away from my character. This always costs me 200$. If I buy a hangar (if this is even possible), can I store it there? And is this the same for all helicopters and planes?

Comment: Is this GTA Online?

Comment: @ardaozkal Ah sure, totally forgot about that. Sry

Comment: fixed tag for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I buy a hangar (if this is even possible) can I store it there?

There are no hangars in GTA Online, unlike GTA V's Single Player Mode.

> And is this the same for all helicopters and planes?

Yes, and not just helicopters and planes, it applies to watercraft and some other big vehicles too, including but not limited to buses and tank.

[Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250411/what-vehicles-are-delivered-with-pegasus/250412#250412) is the list of all vehicles that are delivered by Pegasus.

Comment: I have a yacht with and empty space for a heli. Is it still not possible to put it there?

Comment: @TrudleR unfortunately no. If this answered your question, hit the green mark icon on the question.