# Which vehicles are delivered with Pegasus?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I recently bought a hydra, and saw that it was delivered with Pegasus.

Is there a list of vehicles that get delivered with Pegasus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 81 vehicles that come with Pegasus.

*Extra info:*

If it starts with (E), it is event only (Independence Day Event etc.).

If it starts with (T), it is a transfer bonus (Xbox 360 to Xbox One, Console to PC, PS3 to PS4 etc.).

If you are on PC, you can use this [save file edit](https://www.gta5-mods.com/misc/exclusive-content-for-returning-gtav-unlocker) to unlock it. While there isn't any official word about this, it just changes a variable in your save file to look like a transfered save data, which is probably safe.

If it starts with (U), there are no ways to obtain it. Currently, this only applies to Cargobob. It was never obtainable, other than glitches or hacks.

If it starts with (H), you need to do a heist to unlock it.

**Helicopters**

- Supervolito
- Supervolito Carbon
- Swift Classic
- Swift Flying Bravo
- Swift Deluxe
- Frogger
- Maverick
- (U) Cargobob
- Buzzard Attack Chopper
- Annihilator
- (H) Valkyrie
- (H) Savage

---

**Aeroplanes**

- Shamal
- Mallard
- Luxor
- Luxor Deluxe
- Cuban 800
- Duster
- Mammatus
- Velum
- (H) Velum 5-Seater
- Titan
- Vestra
- Besra
- Miljet
- (T) Dodo
- (H) Hydra

---

**Cars**

- Turreted Limo
- Rhino Tank
- (T) Marshall America
- (T) Marshall Australia
- (T) Marshall Brazil
- (T) Marshall Spain
- (T) Marshall Canada
- (T) Marshall France
- (T) Marshall Germany
- (T) Marshall Japan
- (T) Marshall Scotland
- (T) Marshall Great Britain
- (T) Marshall Italy
- (T) Marshall Switzerland
- (T) Marshall Jamaica
- (T) Marshall Columbia
- (T) Marshall Norway
- (T) Marshall Sweden
- (T) Marshall Belgium
- (T) Marshall Mexico
- (T) Marshall Austria
- (T) Marshall Russia
- (T) Marshall Argentina
- (T) Marshall Turkey
- (T) Marshall Ireland
- (T) Marshall Wales
- (T) Marshall England
- Barracks
- Crusader
- Dump
- Bus
- Airport Bus
- Rental Shuttle Bus
- Prison Bus
- Dashound
- Journey
- (H) Mule
- (H) Boxville
- Stretch
- (E) Liberator
- (H) Insurgent Pick-Up
- (H) Technical

---

**Watercraft**

- Marquis
- Jetmax
- Squalo
- Tropic
- Seashark
- Suntrap
- Speeder
- (T) Kraken
- Dinghy
- Toro